# TFS2012 - Sharepoint "project plan" is not linked to any work items

Tags: sharepoint

I'm quite new with TFS, I'm trying to get our department to use it (and not VSS2005).

I have created a project, user stories and work items.

I'm now playing with the sharepoint portal and have added a "List" which looks like Microsoft Project. I would've thought it would link to all the existing work items and show them, but it is blank.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I sugegst you to access Team Explorer, click on Team Project Settings and Project Portal Settings. Project Portal is not enabled. `Click on Enable team project portal.`

Specify your SharePoint Site credentials and click on OK.

Comment: it is enabled. The dashboard works ok (there are grapohs, etc) I have just added this new list to see what would happen. Perhaps it isn't clever enough. There doesn't seem to be any config for it either.